# Acceder/cerrar un WebSocket implementado con mensajes STOMP /Cerrar WebSocket implementado con STOMP

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

Mi problema es el siguiente , tengo los siguientes archivos de configuracion (adjuntos abajo) y dos problemas principales. [Documentacion de Spring sobre STOMP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-overview)

1. Al lanzar un mensaje por STOMP , ¿Como puedo acceder al WebSocket por el que va?
2. ¿ Como puedo detectar que una peticion STOMP ( o en su defecto un WebSocket ) no estan llegando al front , ya que este se ha desconectado , cerrado el navegador ... o simplemente lleva mucho tiempo inactivo ?

**WebSocketConfig**

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{
  public static final String  ENDPOINT                          = "/notification";

  public static final String  APPLICATION_DESTINATION_PREFIX    = "/app";

  public static final String  GENERIC_QUEUE_DESTINATION_PREFIX  = "/topic";

  public static final String  SPECIFIC_QUEUE_DESTINATION_PREFIX = "/queue";

  public static final String  USER_DESTINATION_PREFIX           = "/user";

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurationReader configReader;

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry)
  {
    registry.addEndpoint(configReader.getApiContext() + ENDPOINT)
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .setHandshakeHandler(new AssignPrincipalHandshakeHandler())
            .addInterceptors(SessionIdHandshakeInterceptor());
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config)
  {
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(APPLICATION_DESTINATION_PREFIX);
    config.enableSimpleBroker(GENERIC_QUEUE_DESTINATION_PREFIX, SPECIFIC_QUEUE_DESTINATION_PREFIX);
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix(USER_DESTINATION_PREFIX);
  }

  @Bean
  public SessionIdHandshakeInterceptor SessionIdHandshakeInterceptor()
  {
    return new SessionIdHandshakeInterceptor();
  }
```

**EventLoggingController**

```
@Controller
public class EventLoggingController
{
  @Autowired
  private EventLoggerManager      manager;

  @Autowired
  private WebsSocketSessionStorage sessionStorage;

  @MessageMapping("/logging")
  public void subscribe(Principal principal,
      SimpMessageHeaderAccessor messageHeaders)
  {
    Session session = sessionStorage.getSession(messageHeaders);
    manager.subscribe(session, principal);
  }
}
```

Cualquier aclaración que necesiteis no teneis mas que pedirla .